# pandas create a column that is a duplicate of the index

Tags: python, pandas

Hopefully this doesn't sound like a silly question but would anyone know how to duplicate a time series index as a pandas df column and strip away the time zone info?

My df index:

```
data_to_keep.index
```

will yield:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2019-06-05 00:00:00+00:00', '2019-07-12 00:00:00+00:00',
               '2019-07-24 00:00:00+00:00', '2019-07-25 00:00:00+00:00',
               '2019-07-26 00:00:00+00:00', '2019-08-02 00:00:00+00:00',
               '2019-08-13 00:00:00+00:00', '2019-08-20 00:00:00+00:00',
               '2019-09-20 00:00:00+00:00', '2019-10-01 00:00:00+00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]', name='Date', freq=None)
```

An attempt to create a df column with this info:

```
data_to_keep['days'] = data_to_keep.index
data_to_keep = data_to_keep[['days']].reset_index()
data_to_keep = data_to_keep.drop('Date', axis=1)
```

This will yield datetime64[ns, UTC]:

```
days
0   2019-06-05 00:00:00+00:00
1   2019-07-12 00:00:00+00:00
2   2019-07-24 00:00:00+00:00
3   2019-07-25 00:00:00+00:00
4   2019-07-26 00:00:00+00:00
5   2019-08-02 00:00:00+00:00
6   2019-08-13 00:00:00+00:00
7   2019-08-20 00:00:00+00:00
8   2019-09-20 00:00:00+00:00
9   2019-10-01 00:00:00+00:00
```

How do I just convert this to string and remove all of the time zone info which is `00:00:00+00:00`?

If I use:

`data_to_keep = data_to_keep.days.astype(str)`

This does convert to strings but how would I get rid of all the `00:00:00+00:00`? So my dataframe would look something like this below:

```
days
0   2019-06-05 
1   2019-07-12 
2   2019-07-24 
3   2019-07-25 
4   2019-07-26 
5   2019-08-02 
6   2019-08-13 
7   2019-08-20 
8   2019-09-20 
9   2019-10-01
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.DatetimeIndex(['2019-06-05 00:00:00+00:00', '2019-07-12 00:00:00+00:00',
               '2019-07-24 00:00:00+00:00', '2019-07-25 00:00:00+00:00',
               '2019-07-26 00:00:00+00:00', '2019-08-02 00:00:00+00:00',
               '2019-08-13 00:00:00+00:00', '2019-08-20 00:00:00+00:00',
               '2019-09-20 00:00:00+00:00', '2019-10-01 00:00:00+00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]', name='Date', freq=None), data={'some_values':range(0,10)})

df['new_col'] = df.index.astype(str).str.split().str[0]

# Out[102]: 
# Date
# 2019-06-05 00:00:00+00:00    2019-06-05
# 2019-07-12 00:00:00+00:00    2019-07-12
# 2019-07-24 00:00:00+00:00    2019-07-24
# 2019-07-25 00:00:00+00:00    2019-07-25
# 2019-07-26 00:00:00+00:00    2019-07-26
# 2019-08-02 00:00:00+00:00    2019-08-02
# 2019-08-13 00:00:00+00:00    2019-08-13
# 2019-08-20 00:00:00+00:00    2019-08-20
# 2019-09-20 00:00:00+00:00    2019-09-20
# 2019-10-01 00:00:00+00:00    2019-10-01
# Name: new_col, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `data_to_keep.index = data_to_keep.index.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`

Do this before you execute the following:

```
data_to_keep['days'] = data_to_keep.index
data_to_keep = data_to_keep.reset_index()
data_to_keep = data_to_keep.drop('Date', axis=1)
```

Comment: The code works, but it still leaves `00:00:00+00:00`

Comment: Did you put my line of code BEFORE doing everything else? To be clear, you have to have this line right at the beginning: `data_to_keep.index = data_to_keep.index.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`

Answer (score 2):

To drop the time zone, run:

```
df.days = df.days.dt.tz_localize(None)
```

The result is:

```
        days
0 2019-06-05
1 2019-07-12
2 2019-07-24
3 2019-07-25
4 2019-07-26
5 2019-08-02
6 2019-08-13
7 2019-08-20
8 2019-09-20
9 2019-10-01
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the column and use the python string replace function to clear the timestamps or use regex.

Since all the timestamps have the same pattern string replace function will be helpful.

I've used the below code and I get rid of all the timestamps on that column.

```
def stamp(col):
for i in range(len(df[col])):
    if(df[col][i]!='present'):
        df[col][i]=df[col][i].replace('0:00','').strip()
```

replace the '0:00' with your timestamp pattern.

here df=dataframe, col=column
my code lookslike this because that dataframe contains more than three columns which contains these types of timestamps.

There is a twist in my code that the column includes the 'present' string which denotes that the employees are still working in the company.

I believe that will help you :)